# Visualize the Pacman

Tags: python, visualization, game-development

I'm writing a simple Pacman game using Q-learning in python 3.11.5, and I'm almost done, but I don't know how to visualize the game, currently, my output is look like this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc9hm.png)

Where:

- W: Wall
- D: Dot
- A: Agent
- E: Empty

I haven't considered ghosts yet, I update the plot every 3 second and use `clear_output()` to clear the
previous map and replace it with new map.

How can I visualize it as an actual pacman game?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score -2):

Depending on your desired result, there are some options.
You could use one of the many GUI toolkits, like `tkinter` (as mentioned in another answer) or [PyQt](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/).

For terminal-only output, some text-oriented UI, like [Curses for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) could be interesting.

Of course, there are also PyGame or the OpenGL bindings to Python, but going from what you posted, these would seem a little over what you currently want.

Answer (score -3):

You have to work with tkinter.
There you can create shapes.

Like this:

```
import tkinter

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 800 # the output window

window = Tk()
window.title("Pac-Man")
c = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, big="black")
c.pack()
wall1 = c.create_rectangle(0, 0, 200, 20) # one wall
```